# compilation of C code showing undefined references when static library (lib.a) has both undefined and defined references

Tags: c, static-libraries, undefined-reference

I am compiling C code and it is stopping with a few undefined references in the linking stage. When I break out the lib.a file into the separate object files, I see that the *.o files contain both undefined and defined values for a particular function (via "nm *.o").  Theoretically, I could step through each of the *.o files and remove the ones that have the undefined values for a function, then rebuild the lib.a file, but this seems to be a ridiculously awkward way to do things.  I must be missing something here...

--Steve

Comment: Do you link with more than one library? Static or dynamic? Please add as many details as possible to your question.

Comment: You need to show more information about the problem.  There isn't enough here for anyone to help you.  The library should normally only call functions in itself, or in more elementary libraries that you also list on the command line.  Such auxilliary libraries will be listed in the documentation for the one you're using.

Comment: I just tried to copy paste the code here but ran out of space by 640 chars!  Is there a way to format code to get around this?  Beyond that, the LDPATH=-L... points to a lib path with both static and dynamic libraries.  I am trying to compile and link this binary statically, so it can run on a mobile device.

Comment: I'd expect the limit on a question to be around 30k characters — unless that's the limit for an answer (I think it's the same, but I've been wrong before).   Work on one of the undefined references — is it called from your code, or from an object file in the library that you need to use (because your code references some other symbol in that object file)?  Where should the function be that it calls (where is the missing reference supposed to be defined)?

Comment: The code is calling a symbol in the static library.  One object file in the static library has the symbol as undefined.  Another object file in the static library has the symbol as defined (symbol T).  Thus my current confusion as to why this is happening.